# How to override "ModuleCore" class? (/classes/module/Module.php)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How to override `ModuleCore` class located in `/classes/module/Module.php`?

If I put `class ModuleOverride extends ModuleCore (...)` in `/override/classes/module/Module.php`, the file is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The override of built in class is the same name without the "Core". In ModuleCore the override class would be just `class Module extends ModuleCore (...)` and the location is correct, the same, but inside the folder override. The Override suffix is for modules classes.
Dont' forget to delete de `cache/class_index.php` file.

Comment: Basically, I had to remove `Override` suffix. Thank you very much.